# Why Swagger javascript ref does work in Schemas

Tags: javascript, express, swagger

I have tow schemas in my aplication, and thats like json inside another json, so i try that

```
    /**
     * @swagger
     * components:
     *   schemas:
     *      IlistItens:
     *        type: object
     *        required:
     *          - name
     *          - isChecked
     *          - tagColor
     *        properties:
     *          name:
     *            type: string
     *            description: name of task
     *          isChecked:
     *            type: boolean
     *            description: check to finish task
     *          tagColor:
     *            type: HexColor
     *            description: Color of task
     *        exemple:
     *          name: Finish the Job
     *          isChecked: false
     *          tagColor: #0099ff
     */
```

And i try to use a ref in my second `interface`.

```
    /**
     * @swagger
     * components:
     *   schemas:
     *      ICardList:
     *        type: object
     *        required:
     *          - title
     *          - listItens
     *        properties:
     *          title:
     *            type: string
     *            description: Title of List
     *          listItens:
     *            type:
     *              $ref: '#/components/schemas/IListItens'
     *        exemple:
     *          title: List Title
     *          listItens: {"name": "Task to do", "isChecked": false, "color": "#0099ff"}
     */
```

but every `$ref: '#/components/schemas/IListItens'` return message error like `Could not resolve reference: #/components/schemas/IListItens` and i search for a solution and read most of forum, i cant find solution. What i did wrong?

Comment: Not sure if that's the reason, but you don't need the `type:` node above the `$ref`. It should be just `listItems: <newline> $ref: '#/...'`.

Comment: I removed for to be ´ listItens: $ref: '#/components/schemas/IListItens'´ but the same error percist, thaks for the help, but this not work 